# how to find if there are no divs present inside the DIv droping_area in JQUery

Tags: jquery

how  to find if there are no divs present inside the DIv droping_area in JQUery

like

```
  <div id="droping_area">

   <div id='a'></div>
   <div id='b'></div>
   <div id='c'></div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var isempty = ($("#droping_area div").length == 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if there are no divs inside your container use `$('#droping_area div').length` property (it should be 0). If you want to make sure if there are no other elements as well use this as a selector:

```
$('#droping_area:empty')
```

This will give you the dropping area `div` only if it will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
$("div", $("#droping_area")).size() == 0
```

Comment: This returns the same number as the 'length' property of the jQuery object. However, it is slightly slower, so length should be used instead.

Comment: @Aaron: But using the parent as context is faster.